# How can I fix the T-SQL editor in VS 2012 after installing SQL Server 2012 SP1?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2012

I can suddenly no longer open .sql files in VS 2012 by simply double clicking in the Solution Explorer. I get the error message:

> Unable to open Transact-SQL file in custom editor

I strongly suspect this is after installing SP1 for SQL Server 2012 Express yesterday, as part of Windows Updates. The error dialogue gives me a link to *Get the latest version of SQL Server Data Tools*, but that link only yields a Page not found on MSDN.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Installing the [SQL Server Data Tools - November 2012 update](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/jj650015) fixed the SQL editor. All is good in the world again.

Comment: This link is correct, they're just referring to it as the "December 2012" update.

Comment: The current new version on the page is June 2013. Looks like it's constantly updated, great!

Comment: My problem is that I DON'T WANT TO OPEN THE FILE IN VISUAL STUDIO.  I want the file to open in SQL Server Management Studio... which is open... and which loads files VERY quickly.  And it used to work just fine.  Ugh.  Now even double-clicking from File Explorer tries to open the SQL files in VS2012, which takes FOREVER.  I hate this.

Comment: @pmbAustin you should open a new question for this issue.  it' s not likely that anyone will answer here.

Comment: @BrianSweeney I have, long ago, accepted an answer, and IMHO, that is enough.

Comment: updated link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh297027. Note that iso links do not work (hope they do in the future)

Answer (score 7):

Yes, yet another bug in SQL Server 2012 *roll eyes*

Right click on the SQL file and choose "Open With...".
Choose "Source Code (Text) Editor" and choose "Set as Default".

Now it works again.

Comment: How is this a fix for the problem? All you've managed to do is to open the a SQL file as a plain text file. You still won't be able to connect with the server explorer or execute queries.

Comment: Ctrl + MAJ +E doesn't run the query

Answer (score 1):

Almost a year later, but I found the answer from joerage to be more helpful.

[Default to the T-SQL Pane view within Visual Studio 2012 Database Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14571098/default-to-the-t-sql-pane-view-within-visual-studio-2012-database-project)