# Cannot open SQL file in T-SQL editor in visual studio 2012

Tags: t-sql, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-data-tools

I have added an sql file to a project in visual studio 2012.  I can open with Source Code (Text) Editor and view the contents of the file.  What I think I should be able to do, is open the file in Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools, T-SQL Editor.  When I do this either visual studio forces a restart or the cursor spins for a while but the file is not opened.  I would like to be able to open an sql file in the T-SQL Editor in visual studio 2012 is that too much to ask microsoft?  What am I doing wrong?

- I have the most current version of SQL Data Tools installed
- I can connect to a database and open new query in T-SQL Editor and
  run it
- I found the following links with similar issues, but none of them solved my problem.

[How can I fix the T-SQL editor in VS 2012 after installing SQL Server 2012 SP1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13667165/how-can-i-fix-the-t-sql-editor-in-vs-2012-after-installing-sql-server-2012-sp1)

[Default to the T-SQL Pane view within Visual Studio 2012 Database Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14571098/default-to-the-t-sql-pane-view-within-visual-studio-2012-database-project)

[Can't load or run a SQL Query in VS 2012](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/vstudio/en-US/3139a20f-f5ae-4333-861a-eec8e38a2f68/cant-load-or-run-a-sql-query-in-vs-2012)

Per request here is the output of the crash.log when I attempt to open an .sql file with T-SQL Editor

```
<record>582</record>
<time>2014/09/26 21:12:08.508</time>
<type>Information</type>
<source>VisualStudio</source>
<description>Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage</description>
<guid>{FEF13793-C947-4FB1-B864-C9F0BE9D9CF6}</guid>
</entry>
<entry>
<record>583</record>
<time>2014/09/26 21:12:08.508</time>
<type>Information</type>
<source>VisualStudio</source>
<description>Begin package load [SqlStudio Editor Package]</description>
<guid>{FEF13793-C947-4FB1-B864-C9F0BE9D9CF6}</guid>
</entry>
<entry>
<record>584</record>
<time>2014/09/26 21:12:08.519</time>
<type>Information</type>
<source>VisualStudio</source>
<description>End package load [SqlStudio Editor Package]</description>
<guid>{FEF13793-C947-4FB1-B864-C9F0BE9D9CF6}</guid>
</entry>
<entry>
<record>585</record>
<time>2014/09/26 21:12:08.662</time>
<type>Information</type>
<source>VisualStudio</source>
<description>Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage</description>
<guid>{ED19932F-5443-4587-A005-1CB9158B2F64}</guid>
</entry>
<entry>
<record>586</record>
<time>2014/09/26 21:12:08.662</time>
<type>Information</type>
<source>VisualStudio</source>
<description>Begin package load [SQL Language Services Package]</description>
<guid>{ED19932F-5443-4587-A005-1CB9158B2F64}</guid>
</entry>
<entry>
<record>587</record>
<time>2014/09/26 21:12:08.681</time>
<type>Information</type>
<source>VisualStudio</source>
<description>End package load [SQL Language Services Package]</description>
<guid>{ED19932F-5443-4587-A005-1CB9158B2F64}</guid>
</entry>
<entry>
<record>588</record>
<time>2014/09/26 21:12:08.843</time>
<type>Information</type>
<source>VisualStudio</source>
<description>Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage</description>
<guid>{0B680757-2C29-4531-80FA-535A5178AA98}</guid>
</entry>
<entry>
<record>589</record>
<time>2014/09/26 21:12:08.843</time>
<type>Information</type>
<source>VisualStudio</source>
<description>Begin package load [Visual Studio Code Snippets Package]</description>
<guid>{0B680757-2C29-4531-80FA-535A5178AA98}</guid>
</entry>
<entry>
<record>590</record>
<time>2014/09/26 21:12:08.843</time>
<type>Information</type>
<source>VisualStudio</source>
<description>End package load [Visual Studio Code Snippets Package]</description>
<guid>{0B680757-2C29-4531-80FA-535A5178AA98}</guid>
</entry>
<entry>
<record>591</record>
<time>2014/09/26 21:12:09.131</time>
<type>Information</type>
<source>VisualStudio</source>
<description>Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage</description>
<guid>{9A62B3CA-5BDF-47CB-A406-3CEB946F1DDF}</guid>
</entry>
<entry>
<record>592</record>
<time>2014/09/26 21:12:09.132</time>
<type>Information</type>
<source>VisualStudio</source>
<description>Begin package load [SqlStudio Debugger Package]</description>
<guid>{9A62B3CA-5BDF-47CB-A406-3CEB946F1DDF}</guid>
</entry>
<entry>
<record>593</record>
<time>2014/09/26 21:12:09.140</time>
<type>Information</type>
<source>VisualStudio</source>
<description>End package load [SqlStudio Debugger Package]</description>
<guid>{9A62B3CA-5BDF-47CB-A406-3CEB946F1DDF}</guid>
</entry>
```

Comment: Can you run `devenv /log crash.log` and see if there is something logged that help identify the issue? Does it repro when you run `devenv /SafeMode`?  Add the results to your question by clicking [edit] ....

Comment: How or where do I run that command?  Do I need to run the visual studio command line to do that?

Comment: yes, open the visual studio command prompt. Make sure to put the crash.log file on a path you can write to. And don't paste the complete log, it can be rather large... just pick the lines that are suspiscous

Answer (score 0):

I had to download and install
**SSDT for Visual Studio (VS) 2012**
Here is the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/previous-releases-of-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt-and-ssdt-bi?view=sql-server-ver16) to the page, if it is broken just search for "sql server data tools 2012".

Here is the link to the download [SSDT_11.0.50730.0_EN.iso](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=518814)

**NOTE** Do not install **Business Solutions**

**Steps**

1. Close **Visual Studio 2012**
2. Download and install **SSDT_11.0.50730.0_EN.iso**
   a. Double click the `.iso` and then double click **SSDTSETUP.EXT**
   b. Check "I agree..." and **Install**
   [image]
3. On the **Setup Successful** screen click **Close**
   [image]
4. Restart computer
5. Open **Visual Studio 2012**
6. Right-Click a `.sql` file
   a. Click **Open with...**
   [image]
   b. Choose **Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools, T-SQL Editor**
   c. Click the **Set as Default** button
   d. Click **OK**