# Visual Studio 2010 Toolbar Menu

Tags: visual-studio-2010

can someone help me to find missing "Data" menu from toolbar in VS 2010?

I also cannot run tsql code as Connect button after right-clicking the code is somehow not showing up. Visual Studio was installed as part of SQL Server 2012 Developer Edition

thank you very much

links to images:
http://i41.tinypic.com/2vwbvhu.gif

http://i39.tinypic.com/2hp175g.gif

Answer (score 0):

It appears the data menu is being phased out (I'm still seeing the Data menu in VS 2010 Express, but it seems that it's gone not only in your scenario but with VS 2012).  The two items in the menu, `Show Data Sources` and `Add New Data Source...` can be reached by using the keyboard shortcut `Shift+Alt+D`, or quite possibly in your version, under the `View` menu -> `Other Windows` -> `Data Sources`.

Main source: [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5a410b49-fd1a-4458-814a-dcb12a2c24a0/data-menu-option-missing-in-vs2012-ultimate).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Though as mentioned in a thread from your link, it did not work. Menu is different. Also T-SQL editor is missing

Comment: @JankaP: Hmm.  Just to clarify for whoever might help, the thread only explicitly mentions the original Data menu and suggested option #1 (using Team Explorer) not working.  Neither Shift+Alt+D nor using the View menu work?  For the T-SQL editor, perhaps the update suggested in [this SO topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13667165/how-can-i-fix-the-t-sql-editor-in-vs-2012-after-installing-sql-server-2012-sp1) will help.